# Plotting a function $\phi: C \to R$ in $R^3$ by writing it in terms of $\phi: R \times R \to R$.

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

I have a complex polynomial $f(z)$ and I would like to plot a 3D graph that takes in $x$ and $y$ (as the real/imaginary parts) and outputs the modulus of the result. How can I write, for example $z=1+(x+iy)+(x+iy)^2$ without using $i$?

The 3D graphing program I have will only accept functions of the form $\phi: R^2 \to R$.

Answer (score 0):

Define (or do it a priori on paper) the function $\Psi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ by sending $(x,y)$ into $x+iy$. This is a homeomorphism so there's no data lost, and obviously $\Psi^{-1}$ sends $x+iy$ into $(x,y)$. Now work with the function $\Psi\circ f\circ \Psi^{-1}$, which is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Now define the absolute value function normally for it and plot.

Comment: You should write your polynomial as $f(z)=Re(f(z))+iIm(f(z))$ for easier work.